# Speed up plot of $\sum_{j\ge1} 2^{-j}(1-2^{-j})^{n-1}$

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, summation

I'm a beginner at Mathematica. I would like to plot the following function:

$${n\over2} \sum_{j\ge1} 2^{-j}(1-2^{-j})^{n-1}$$

However the following code is just too slow:

```
Plot[n/2 NSum[2^(-j) (1 - 2^(-j))^(n - 1), {j, 1, Infinity}], {n, 1, 100}]
```

I think it may be trying to expand the $(n-1)$th power symbolically instead of numerically. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can try giving the following options to Plot, and tweak them until you have a good speed/quality trade-off: `PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 3` If you search the site for those options you'll find more in-depth explanations and examples :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know in advance that your sum is already convergent, you can skip the convergence check. Also, it sometimes helps to change the `Method` used by `NSum[]`. Here, I use the [Shanks transformation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1956-0084056-6) as the summation method:

```
Plot[n/2 NSum[2^(-j) (1 - 2^(-j))^(n - 1), {j, 1, ∞}, 
              Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", Degree -> 2, "ExtraTerms" -> 30}, 
              NSumTerms -> 50, VerifyConvergence -> False], {n, 1, 100}, 
     Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0.72, 0.724}]
```

[image: plot of the sum]

Comment: Much faster, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is an approximation, but the result is immediate calculating over the integers:

```
f[n_] := Sum[2^(-j) (1 - 2^(-j))^(n - 1), {j, 1, Infinity}]

DiscretePlot[n/2 f@n, {n, 1, 101}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0.72, 0.724}]
```

[image]